# SQL query to filter many-to-many

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many

I have users, groups and users_groups tables set up as below:

```
users
  id int

groups
  id int

users_groups
  user_id int
  group_id int
```

Example Data

```
+-------+--------+
|user_id|group_id|
+-------+--------+
|  1    |    1   |
|  1    |    2   |
|  1    |    3   |
|  2    |    1   |
|  2    |    2   |
|  3    |    2   |
|  3    |    3   |
+-------+--------+
```

Is there a way to select all users who belong to a subset of groups which has an unknown size? This is essentially filtering based on the group ids.

For example a query that returns user ids for members of groups 1 and 2 would return a user ids of [1,2], but then when asked for members of groups 1,2 and 3 returns a user id of [1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only users being in all 3 groups use

```
select user_id
from users_groups ug
where group_id in (1,2,3)
group by user_id
having count(distinct group_id) = 3
```

Comment: +1 for that, I've been busy creating fiddle demo with function, so answered after you :)

Answer (score 1):

basically you can do this by aggregating and counting number of entries. You can do this by simple query, like juergen_d did, or use function like this:

```
create function fn_users_groups(_groups int[])
returns table(user_id int)
as
$$
    select user_id
    from users_groups
    where group_id = any(_groups)
    group by user_id
    having count(*) = array_length(_groups, 1)
$$
language sql;
```

**[=> sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/6af32/1)**